# how to set image on circular slider IOS

Tags: ios, slider

I download one Circular Slider Demo Project From this link [This Is Downlaod Link](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/uicircularslider)
In This Demo Project i don't understand how to replace thumb image . If you know any circular slider where i change thumb image please share with me link 
Please Help me

Comment: Please Give me Solution

Comment: It's possible to change the thumbImage in slider with your custom image, please check below answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the Image to the Thumb of slider, but you can set any color to that Thumb by this:

```
self.circularSlider.thumbTintColor=[UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: is any hope any demo for me . how i change Please help me

Answer (score 0):

#### You can change image in slider by setting thumbImage to your custom image.

```
 slider.setThumbImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "select"), for: .normal)
 slider.setThumbImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "select"), for: .highlighted)
```

## Output:

[image: image1]

Even if you can change certain other things like:

```
  slider.thumbTintColor = .green // when there is no custom image for ThumbImage
  slider.minimumTrackTintColor = .red
  slider.maximumTrackTintColor = .blue
```

## Output:

[image: image2]